# pdf's made from markdown with pandoc eliminate the double space after a period

Tags: css, pdf, markdown, wkhtmltopdf, pandoc

I have markdown documents that I create pdf's from with a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euxo pipefail
MARGIN=.35in
pandoc -t html5 -V margin-top=$MARGIN -V margin-left=$MARGIN -V margin-bottom=$MARGIN -V margin-right=$MARGIN -V papersize=letter --css ~/bin/inc/pandoc-pdf.css $1 -o $2 -s --pdf-engine=wkhtmltopdf
```

It does the job ok... except that sentences are mushed-together by the double spaces being removed.  It makes sense that's happening because it's generating html and using css to create the pdf.

I can sorta work around that by doing a search/replace `%s/  / \&nsbp;/g` and this results in better spacing... except when the line mid-paragraph begins with a new sentence, in which case the `&nsbp;` character creates an unwanted space at the beginning of the line.

Does anyone have solution for this?  I'd much rather avoid inserting `&nbsp;` characters throughout my documents (and then removing them after pdf generation).

I'd even settle for a better markdown-to-pdf process without css, but I've spent several hours on that and this `pdf-engine=wkhtmltopdf` + css is the best thing I've seen thus far.

Comment: haha, I won't try to understand you double-space people ;-) dunno, maybe add some CSS? for alternative PDF-generation methods, see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf

Comment: Two spaces between sentences are generally [frowned upon](https://practicaltypography.com/one-space-between-sentences.html) by typography experts. Are you sure you really need them?

Comment: haha, I thought that was just for the web.  my typography books concur.  "double-space people" are just a result of bad education.

Comment: ...bad education and the fact that word-processors neglect to auto-correct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that single-spaces after a sentence is not just a web convention but a print convention too it's highly unlikely that there will be an elegant technical solution for achieving this bad-practice of typography.  So the solution in this case is easy, use proper practice of typography :)